# Using a supertype parameter of specific enum classes

Tags: java, enums

I have two parser classes, and I want to throw an exception when parsing fails.
I want to use the same exception, ParserException, which I'd like could accept the field name which caused the failure. I thought to use enums, but I think I don't have the topic completely clear.

**How do I declare fieldName in the ParserException class?** enum, as far as I understand, should be the supertype for ParserA.Fields and ParserB.Fields, but is not accepted.

Please note that **the two enum classes contain a different set of enums**, i.e. they are not the same class.

```
public class ParserA {

 public enum Fields {
  A_FIRST_FIELD
  A_SECOND_FIELD
 }


 public void parse() {
  ... 
 throw ParserException(Fields.A_FIRST_FIELD);  
 }

}

public class ParserB {

 public enum Fields {
  B_FIRST_FIELD
  B_SECOND_FIELD
 }

 public void parse() {
  ... 
  throw ParserException(Fields.B_FIRST_FIELD);  
 }

}



// Parser error
public class ParserException extends Exception {

 enum fieldName; // ????? what goes here?


 public ParserException(enum e) {
  this.fieldName = e;
 }

 public enum getFieldName() {  // ?????? how do I do something like this?
  return fieldName;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *could* have `ParserException` store an `Enum<?>`, but this really doesn't provide you any real advantage over just using `Object` as the type for the field in `ParserException`.

Short of changing the design of what you're doing here, my preference would be to make a marker interface called `Field` and have all your `enum`s that represent fields implement that... then `ParserException` could use `Field` as the type of object it stores.

```
public interface Field {
}

...

public enum Fields implements Field {
  A_FIRST_FIELD,
  A_SECOND_FIELD
}

...

public class ParserException extends Exception {
  private final Field field;

  public ParserException(Field field) {
    this.field = field;
  }

  public Field getField() {
    return field;
  }
}
```

For the most part, that something is an `enum` should be an implementation detail that nothing else should have to care about.

Comment: `This really doesn't provide you any real advantage over just using Object` - It does, methods `name()` and `ordinal()` may be really handy. OTOH, you can't get more this way.

Comment: @maaartinus: `toString()` is equivalent to `name()` unless you override `toString()`... and the Javadoc for `name()` suggests that `toString()` be used in preference to it in most cases. `ordinal()` is not intended for normal use... it's "designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures".

Comment: I disagree. "*Most programmers should use the toString method in preference to this one*" - this sounds strange. `toString()` should be used for humans, but the program behavior should not rely on it. That's what `name()` is for. And who knows if cdarwin is going to make sophisticated structures with `ordinal()`? Sure, there's not much you can do, especially when you don't know which of the two enums you've got.

Comment: @maaartinus: It's _extremely_ unlikely that he needs the `ordinal()` method... `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` are the main places where it's needed. Also, in his example he doesn't override `toString()` for his enums, so it's going to do exactly the same as `name()`. Realistically, it's highly unlikely that there is any advantage to keeping the `Enum<?>` type around in the exception, period.

Comment: `It's extremely unlikely that he needs the ordinal() method`  that's just bloody incorrect. External storages/transports scream for ordinal(), name() can have any arbitrary length (which blows). An enum constant allows for full 'introspection' of the possible values as well. Enums are comparable (which is underused but a great feature). Plus, no one should use toString() of enum for anything but human representation.

Comment: @bestsss: Using `ordinal()` for external storage is a terrible idea since it can change so easily if you decide you want to add a new constant before one of the existing ones. You should use your own ID or whatever that you have full control over (regardless of how you order your constants). You're missing the point though. It's not that there's never ever ever ever any reason someone might want to use `name()` or `ordinal()`, but that it's unlikely that there's actually any need for them in this situation, which I still maintain is true.

Comment: @ColinD: if you worry about bumping on a new enum constant, you opt for ordinal()+hash(name)

Comment: @bestsss: I don't see how that helps anything. `ordinal()` was most definitely not made for use with external persistence of an `enum` constant.

Answer (score 1):

> enum, as far as I understand, should be the supertype for ParserA.Fields and ParserB.Fields

Not **enum**, but **Enum** is the common supertype (or more precisely `Enum<?>`). But probably you don't want to use it, it's too general. It could be better to use something like

```
 // ParserExceptionKind is probably a better name
 public interface ParserEnum { 
      String name();
      // some useful methods go here
 }

 public class ParserA implements ParserEnum {
      public enum Fields {
           A_FIRST_FIELD
      }
 }

 public class ParserException extends Exception {
      private ParserEnum parserEnum;
      ...
 }
```

However, most of the time it's better to create separate subclasses of Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Fields` type, like you would do with normal class.

```
Fields fieldName;
```

And similar in other cases.

BTW, enums are usually named in singular case (again, just like with classes, enums aren't *that* different).

**edit**
You can use `Enum` class (common superclass for all enums), or even `Object`.

But frankly, I see little point in declaring enum class with one element. You could've just used string constants: same functionality and less confusing.

Comment: @cdarwin In this case, `Enum` should do. Although it doesn't help a lot, name might as well have been a string.

Answer (score 0):

`ParserA.Fields` and `ParserB.Fields` have no common super class, (except for the raw type `Enum` or `Object`, but I doubt that that's going to help you here).

Since enums can't be extended, I don't see how you would be able to solve this using enums.

You could work around this by changing `enum` into `class` and let both `ParserA.Field` and `ParserB.Field` extend `ParserException.Field`. In order to have the same advantages as `enums` however, you would have to limit the number of instances. There are several ways of achieving this, such as making the constructor protected, and have a limited number of public static members of this type.

Comment: I also accept different solutions... but I think that in some way enums should be used

Comment: -1 Changing enums to classes just for this use case doesn't seem acceptable. An interface is appropriate if you want multiple enums to implement some common type.